# How to parse a UTC date/time in Java

Tags: java, datetime

Given a date/time String in this format:
`2021-12-05 21:10:00 UTC`, how do I parse it into a Java DateTime object?
It seems to require a formatter string such as `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, but what do I do with the "UTC" and how do I make sure the Java object specifies UTC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing you're missing is a timezone specifier, eg. `z`.

```java
// first
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

//then
String dateString = "2021-12-05 21:10:00 UTC";
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, DATETIME_PARSER);
```

This correctly produces the date-time object you need.

That said, it's unclear whether you need `z` (time-zone name), `VV` (time-zone ID), or `v` (generic time-zone name) as they all mean something slightly different and all will work with "UTC". See the [documentation for the supported formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).

---

EDIT:

> The data comes from an environmental sensor whose location is known, and the only thing that matters is that the date/time value is UTC.

In that case it does not matter, just use `z`.

As a commenter rightfully suggested, you might want to use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) instead of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) if all you care about is the point on the timeline and you do not care about the timezone the event originated from:

```java
Instant instant = Instant.from(DATETIME_PARSER.parse(dateString));
```

Comment: Thanks. The data comes from an environmental sensor whose location is known, and the only thing that matters is that the date/time value is UTC. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @RobertLewis I edited my answer, just use `z` and consider using an `Instant` instead of `ZonedDateTime` as that looks like it models your situation better.